# Defining type and value aliases at the same time in scala

Tags: scala

Here is an example from Scala Cookbook:

```
package com.alvinalexander.myapp

package object model {

    // field
    val MAGIC_NUM = 42

    // method
    def echo(a: Any) { println(a) }

    // enumeration
    object Margin extends Enumeration {
        type Margin = Value
        val TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT = Value
    }

    // type definition
    type MutableMap[K, V] = scala.collection.mutable.Map[K, V]
    val MutableMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map

}
```

Aren't these two lines doing the same thing?

```
    type MutableMap[K, V] = scala.collection.mutable.Map[K, V]
    val MutableMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map
```

Or, can't I just

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => MutableMap}
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Aren't these two lines doing the same thing?

```
type MutableMap[K, V] = scala.collection.mutable.Map[K, V]
val MutableMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map
```

They are not. `type MutableMap[K, V] = scala.collection.mutable.Map[K, V]` is a type alias.

```
scala> val m: MutableMap[String, Int] = scala.collection.mutable.Map("a" -> 1)
m: MutableMap[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1)
```

But the following would not work with the type alias alone:

```
scala> val m: MutableMap[String, Int] = MutableMap("a" -> 1)
<console>:11: error: not found: value MutableMap
       val m: MutableMap[String, Int] = MutableMap("a" -> 1)
                                        ^
```

`val MutableMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map` is simply creating a copy of `mutable.Map`'s companion object. That is, it is a value, and not a type. It would also not work by itself:

```
scala> val m: MutableMap[String, Int] = MutableMap("a" -> 1)
<console>:11: error: not found: type MutableMap
       val m: MutableMap[String, Int] = MutableMap("a" -> 1)
              ^
```

In short, the difference is that one is for a *type*, and one a *value*.

`import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => MutableMap}` will alias both the type, and the value (companion object). Generally, this is what you would want.